Event de-duplication is not working in Flink with RabbitMQ connector
I have a Flink job with a RMQ source, tumbling windows (fires for each 2s), an aggregator, then a RMQ sink. Incremental RocksDB checkpointing is enabled with an interval of 5 minutes.
I was trying to understand Flink failure recovery. My checkpoint X is started,  I have sent one event to my source. As windows are triggered every 2s, my sink is updated with the aggregated result. But when I checked the RabbitMQ console, my source queue still had unacked messages. (It is expected and it is as per design https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.19/docs/connectors/datastream/rabbitmq/#rabbitmq-source).
Now I restarted my task manager, as restart happens within the same checkpoint interval and checkpoint X has not yet completed. The message is not acknowledged and is sent again. Duplicate processing of events happens.
How to avoid these duplicates?

i have got a reply from flink user chain that it is an issue with flink rabbitmq connector. If needed people can create jira issue and fix. For kafka sink , transactions are supported so deduplication works fine.. but in rabbitmq sink transactions are not supported. transactions are supported only in rmqsource side.  At the end ofcheckpoint completion only, all the events received during the window will be acknowledged using acknowledge all mechanism. For now i am keeping my window time and checkpoint time both as same values ie 10s
